# Creat Custom Lead Conversion Process

Tags: apex, visualforce, leads, lead-conversion

I want to create a custom lead conversion process.
The desired functionalities would all be achieved by customizing the lead conversion page. I want:

1. To not have to create an opportunity or a task during conversion (not even display the options)
2. To only allow merges into existing accounts (if and only if a condition [custom field on the account]) and not the creation of new accounts

The business reason behind this, is that we have an active offline process for supply acquisition. We want to support and especially track that process through salesforce. A supply is considered to be acquired, as soon as he lists his product on our platform. Therefore I only want to allow the conversion of a lead after said condition is met.

I am currently trying to figure out the best approach would be to achieve my desired goal.

I am thinking that the best way would be to:

1. Create a custom Visualforce Page
2. Create an extension of the standard lead controller
3. Validate that the condition is met through a lookup on the extension
4. Convert the Lead through the Database.LeadConvert() class

Does this make sense and would you have any ideas for improving upon my proposed approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense the approach you have defined. Since you want to have a full blown custom experience, you will need to create a custom page to suffice the requirement. I do not believe you can modify the standard lead conversion page layout and if the UI is so important, then just having an Apex trigger instead will not help. You can create a Custom Button, override that with the VF page and place the button on the Lead Page Layout.

As you wrote, you will have to play with `Database.LeadConvert` class and `Database.convertLead` method in your Apex before you convert the Lead. If you do not want Opportunity to be created then, you need to use `setDoNotCreateOpportunity` method, with **true** as parameter to be passed.

To merge a Lead with existing account, you can use `setAccountId` method and pass in the **ID** of your existing Account.

For better user experience, you must:

1. Make sure only relevant and concise information is available on the VF page.
2. You handle all your validation errors gracefully and provide necessary information to the user.
3. Incorporate HelpTexts on the VF page so users are aware of the meaning of the different parts of the UI.
4. Try to emulate the Salesforce UI so that users do not see big differences if they already have been using this feature in Salesforce.

There may be different optimizations in the UI based on your expertise. However, in my opinion, Apex optimizations are more important.

Comment: appreciate the feedback. I have since found a pretty neat package and started looking into the package http://www.topalovich.com/2014/02/salesforce-custom-convert-lead-page-and-lead-conversion-process-using-visualforce-and-apex/
I will probably customize this. Would you by any chance have some info on how to check if the account has a certain field set?

Comment: Are you talking about Salesforce FieldSets?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fieldsets_describe.htm

Comment: Haha no, I meant if a custom field is set to a specific values, more precisely, if it's greater than 0.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215217/remove-create-new-account-xxx-from-picklist