# Remove "Create New Account: xxx" from picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce, account, lead-conversion

I have the following code on my Apex component as part of a custom lead conversion process. The user can select an account here **OR** create a new account. I want to remove the "Create New Account: xxx" from the picklist. Any idea how to do so?

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedAccount}" size="1" 
    multiselect="false" id="accountList">

    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
        action="{!accountChanged}" 
        rerender="opportunityName, ViewLink"
         />     
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!accounts}"/>

</apex:selectList>
```

I figured it out, its part of the controller

```
private void populateAccounts() {

    if (leadConvert != null) {

        string company = leadConvert.Company;

        // find any accounts that match the SOSL query in the findCompany() method  
        Account [] accountsFound = findCompany(company + '*');

        accounts = new List<selectOption>();

        if (accountsFound != null && accountsFound.size() > 0) {

            // if there is at least 1 account found add a NONE option and a Create New Account option
            accounts.add(new SelectOption('NONE', '-None-'));

            accounts.add(new SelectOption('NEW', 'Create New Account: ' + company ));

            // for each account found, add an option to attach to the existing account
            for (Account a : accountsFound) {

                accounts.add(new SelectOption(a.Id, EXISTING + a.Name));
            }

        }

        else {

            // if no accounts matched then simply add a Create New Account option
            accounts.add(new SelectOption('NEW', 'Create New Account: ' + company ));

            system.debug('no account matches on company ' + company);
        }

        //the default opportunity name will be the lead's company
        opportunityId.Name = company + '-';
    }

    else system.debug('leadConvert = null');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to add option in picklist. Just comment this line in code

```
//accounts.add(new SelectOption('NEW', 'Create New Account: ' + company ));
```